# Particles falling towards a singularity

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, event-horizon, singularities

This is a revision of my earlier question.  Sorry. I'm a beginner here and on a learning curve regarding format.

If the gravity well steepens to infinity at the point of a singularity, then so does the "time well".  Understandingly, the inward falling energy/matter is not aware of this change in time relative to the "outside" universe, locked as it is in its local reference.  How does the inward falling energy/matter ever "physically" reach the singularity?

It seems like the man counting to 100, going half way each time.  He gets closer and closer, but never actually arrives 100% there.

Comment: Hey Curious Steve, we much prefer that you don't repost questions. Instead, it's best to edit your original question. After being edited (at least the first time), it gets put in a queue to be reviewed for having the hold removed.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thank you.